# Quit channel on a worker pool implementation

Tags: go, goroutine

What I eventually want to accomplish is to dynamically scale my workers up OR down, depending on the workload.

The code below successfully parses data when a Task is coming through w.Channel

```
func (s *Storage) StartWorker(w *app.Worker) {

    go func() {

        for {

            w.Pool <- w.Channel // register current worker to the worker pool

            select {

            case task := <-w.Channel: // received a work request, do some work

                time.Sleep(task.Delay)

                fmt.Println(w.WorkerID, "processing task:", task.TaskName)

                w.Results <- s.ProcessTask(w, &task)

            case <-w.Quit:
                fmt.Println("Closing channel for", w.WorkerID)
                return
            }

        }
    }()

}
```

The blocking point here is the line below.

```
w.Pool <- w.Channel
```

In that sense, if I try to stop a worker(s) in any part of my program with:

```
w.Quit <- true
```

the `case <-w.Quit:` is blocked and never receives until there's another incoming Task on **w.Channel** (and I guess select statement here is random for each case selection).

So how can I stop a channel(worker) independently?

Comment: Why send a single "quit" message? Why not put `w.Pool <- w.Channel` in a select? Just close the channel and check the `Quit` channel wherever you need to (or maybe even use a Context)

Comment: @JimB do you think that case w.Pool <- w.Channel: task := <-w.Channel is the way to go with this ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this is supposed to do. You appear to be receiving from the same channel to do two different things. Why do you need to "register"? Start the workers and accept tasks for them. You are also attempting to implement a "quit" channel, but you have no way to actually determine when the workers have quit.

Comment: @JimB I have wait groups for that on both the dispatcher handling worker goroutines and on my queues handling tasks goroutines. I just omitted the code here. So everything quits properly if there are no task or worker goroutines (Like delayed tasks, retrying tasks etc). I just needed the proper, non-blocking way to send the quit signal in order to start closing the channels down. The register part is due to the fact that I have multiple dispatchers. Maybe I over complicate things here, but putting the w.Pool <- w.Channel in a select helped me.

Answer (score 0):

See below sample code, it declares a fanout function that is reponsible to size up/down the workers.

It works by using timeouts to detect that new workers has ended or are required to spawn.

there is an inner loop to ensure that each item is processed before moving on, blocking the source when it is needed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    input := make(chan string)
    fanout(input)
}

func fanout() {
    workers := 0
    distribute := make(chan string)
    workerEnd := make(chan bool)
    for i := range input {
        done := false 
        for done {
            select {
            case distribute<-i:
                done = true
            case <-workerEnd:
                workers--
            default:
                if workers <10 {
                    workers++
                    go func(){
                        work(distribute)
                        workerEnd<-true
                    }()
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}

func work(input chan string) {
    for  {
        select {
        case i := <-input:
            <-time.After(time.Millisecond)
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            return
        }

    }
}
```